# Submit 2000 Form with loop

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to submit 2000 forms, in a loop with each submit delayed 6 seconds. That means that, after 12000 seconds all forms ware submited.

In addition, I should say that I can't use Ajax or cURL. 
Just I can use only the `Form submit()` function from jQuery, because the server blocked other ways.

I have tried this code but it doesn't  work:

```js
x= 0;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
 x++;
 window.setInterval(function(){ $('form[target*=x'+x+']').submit();} ,6000);
}
```

This code just submits last form, meaning form number 100!!!

Thank you!

Comment: why are you trying to do?

Comment: You have to use AJAX. Normal form submission reloads the page and stops the script.

Comment: Are you trying to build a brute-force cracker ?

Comment: OP writes thank you bro to the  Tiberiu C who answered OP, but OP do not even accept his answer, @MusicSara you can at least accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot understand why you say that cURL or Ajax doesn't work as long as one can act like a browser request and the other one runs on the client side. As long as you can see the page in the browser and js is enabled, both should work.

However, I do have an answer for you:  submit to an `iframe` target.

This won't reload the page and if the script is from the same domain (no cross domain violations) you can have access to the content of the response.

Presumably you have this kind of HTML arrangement in the page:

```
<form action="?" method="post">
  <input name="name" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form action="?" method="post">
  <input name="name" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form action="?" method="post">
  <input name="name" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form action="?" method="post">
  <input name="name" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form action="?" method="post">
  <input name="name" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form action="?" method="post">
  <input name="name" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
.....
```

### Javascript

This little script adds an `iframe` to the page, gets the forms and submits them to the previously created `iframe`:

```
var $frame = $('<iframe name="post_form_frame" style="display:block">');
$('body').append($frame);

var frameName = $frame.attr('name');

var $forms = $('form');
var submitInterval = 6000;
var size = $forms.size();
var current = 0;

var submitChain = function(){
   if (size === current){
     //console.log('finished');
     return;
   }
   var $form = $forms.eq(current);
   // store the assign target 
   var target = $form.attr('target');
   // set the attribute and submit
   $form.attr('target', frameName).submit();
   //console.log('form '+current + ' submitted');
   $form.attr('target', target);
   current++; // increment the current
   setTimeout(submitChain, submitInterval); // schedule next submission
};

submitChain();
```

A simulation is here : http://jsbin.com/xabuvi/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Tnx bro It Helps Me So much.Good Luck Bro